# How to use jquery to get values from multiple forms

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple forms that are created via php and it displays like this:

```
<form id='0' class='forms' name='input[0]' action='correct_exec.php' method='GET'>
<input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[0]' value='00000000c83de86'>
<input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[0]' value='1'>
<input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[0]' value='2014-02-24 05:00:03'>
<tr>
    <td align='center'>2014-02-24<BR />05:00:03</td>
    <td>

                <img src='../ocr-results/00000000c83de86f_1_2014-02-24_05h00m03s.jpg'><BR />
<input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[0]' value='0366167'>
    </td>
    <td><input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='train[0]' value='False'>
<input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[0]' value='True' >
</td>
    <td><input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='valid[0]' value='False'>
<input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='valid[0]' value='True' >
</td>
    <td><button id='submit_button' class='0' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
<form id='1' class='forms' name='input[1]' action='correct_exec.php' method='GET'>
<input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[1]' value='00000000c83de86'>
<input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[1]' value='1'>
<input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[1]' value='2014-02-24 04:00:03'>
<tr>
    <td align='center'>2014-02-24<BR />04:00:03</td>
    <td>

                <img src='../ocr-results/00000000c83de86f_1_2014-02-24_04h00m03s.jpg'><BR />
<input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[1]' value='0366132'>
    </td>
    <td><input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='train[1]' value='False'>
<input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[1]' value='True' >
</td>
    <td><input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='valid[1]' value='False'>
<input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='valid[1]' value='True' >
</td>
    <td><button id='submit_button' class='1' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

This is not limited to 2 different forms, it can continue as I can have 10 to 20 different forms. In fact, those are records coming from a database and I want to update them without reloading the page.

So first I tried this code to only get the values selected from the click of the button:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.forms').submit(function(){
                var name = $('.rpiid', this).attr('name');
                var value = $('.rpiid', this).val();
                alert('the name is:' + name + ' and the value is ' + value);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But unfortunately, it gives me undefined for both values :(.

Thanks to help,

John.

Comment: why dont you use $('#id').val() instead of 'this' using id you can get data from else where in the HTML

Comment: This code worked fine for me, have you called the jQuery library?

Comment: yes, I have the line at the begining of the code:<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script> -> does it need to be encapsulated in <head> ???

Comment: @user2040597 Not necessarily, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLCJ5/) of your code, you would have to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: Here is my fiddle and I have the same issue :( http://jsfiddle.net/BLCJ5/

Comment: you have not selected jquery library there.

Comment: under `Frameworks & Extensions` you can see one `select box`. there select jquery library

Comment: Ok, I changed it but I still get the undefined value that is returned. The fiddle now is: http://jsfiddle.net/starcraft04/BLCJ5/4/